# Убрать последнюю запятую в массиве из генерируемых элементов

Tags: php, битрикс

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "FAQPage",
      "mainEntity": [
      <? foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem):  
      $name = strip_tags($arItem['NAME']);
      $text = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"),' ', trim(strip_tags($arItem['PREVIEW_TEXT'])));
      ?>
      {
        "@type": "Question",
        "name": "<?=$name?>",
        "acceptedAnswer": {
          "@type": "Answer",
          "text": "<?=$text?>"
        }
      } ,
      <? endforeach; ?>
      ]
    }
</script>
```

Подскажите,пожалуйста, как после последнего элемента убрать запятую(перед конструкцией endforeach ). Перебрал все похожие варианты с сайта, ничего не подходит.
заранее спасибо

Comment: Ты сотворил франкенштейна (с)

Comment: Эт не я сделал, мне это поправить надо)

Comment: Можно попробовать заменить foreach на for и в каждой итерации проверять, $elem[$i + 1] == NULL)

Comment: Не ,к сожалению не подходит , надо сохранить именно цикл for each

Comment: Тогда обїявите $count перед циклом и увеличивайте в итерациях, в таком случае придется проверять $arResult["ITEMS"][$count + 1] на существование.

Comment: А что записать после проверки , каким образом убрать запятую , на ум приходит только implode ?, но как его здесь применить , не могу понять. Я в php еще нубяра, .

Comment: Та не, там условие, ```if(["ITEMS"][$count + 1]  != null) { echo "," } ```

Comment: Храни Вас Господь , получилось , спасибо!

Comment: На здоровье, рад помочь)